# Homotoping non zero degree arbitrary maps to a covering map

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, covering-spaces

Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a non zero degree smooth map between compact connected oriented manifolds of the same dimension. Must  $f$ be homotopic to a covering map ?

This seems too good to be true, So I m expecting counterexamples

Comment: Maybe you could expect a ramified covering, but this fails too probably. The obstruction would be harder to find, however. For the future, surgery theory is a very rich subject that can answer questions like this.

Comment: @AndreaMarino: No, ramified covering maps are not enough. Consider a degree one map $T^2\to S^2$. It cannot be homotopic to a ramified covering map.

Comment: @moishe kohen $T^2$ is $S^1\times S^1$ , no ?

Comment: If yes, then what would be an example of a degree 1 map from the torus to the sphere ? I was only able to find degree 0 maps

Comment: @Amr: Yes, of course. It is a good exercise to find such a degree 1 map (it might take you more than 10 minutes).

Comment: Hmmm ok. I tried the map which mimics Euler angles but computed it's degree to be 0. Let me think abt it more

Comment: No, forget Euler angles, think of the torus as the square with standard identification and of $S^2$ as the quotient $D^2/\partial D^2$.

Comment: Oppps :) ok got it.

Comment: I think part of why I didn't think in terms of cell complex structure, is that I was constantly thinking of intersection numbers as defined in differential topology using transversality

Comment: Another good exercise is to show that a degree one map $T^2\to S^2$ cannot be be a ramified covering.

Comment: I know it can't be a covering map because S2 is simply connected while the torus isn't. However u say the word "ratified covering " which I assume to be something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is a map $f_d : S^2 \to S^2$ with $\deg f_d = d$. On the other hand, as $S^2$ is simply connected, the only connected covering is $\operatorname{id} : S^2 \to S^2$ which has degree $1$. As degree is a homotopy invariant, we see that the claim is false.

Comment: Opps I missed that lol +1